# Cron expression with excluding of a specific day of week

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want to create cron expression for a my job, but I don't know, how I can excluded specific day of week from expression.

```
triggerBuilder
       .ForJob(jobKey)
       .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule("????")).InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
       .StartNow()
       .WithIdentity(triggerKey)
       .Build();
```

For example: I want to fire my job every day except Monday.

I found approach where we can set firing of job at noon (12 PM) every day from interval:

`0 0 0 ? * MON-FRI` or `0 0 0 ? * 1-5`

but what about excepting specific day from this interval, for example "Thursday".

Thanks for a help :)

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cronmaker.com/

Comment: @DanielKelley, cool thanks! I don't know about this resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [cronmaker.com](http://cronmaker.com), an example Cron schedule that executes every day except Monday at 12pm would be:

```
0 0 12 ? * TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT,SUN *
```

Obviously the site will let you tailor this as required, but hopefully if the site ever goes down, and someone has a similar example, they will be able to use this expression as a guide to creating their own.